# How to get the translations of a key in a particular language using angular $translate

Tags: html, angularjs, localization, translation

Is there a way to get the translation in a particular language using angualar $translate from inside a controller? $translate.instant(KEY) return the translation of the key based on the selected language . What I need is something like
For example if I have already defined the translations in two languages: english and spanish , then $translate.Somefunction(KEY,"languagekey")

Answer (score 0):

I am not a `$translate` expert, but can you change the preferred language, do the translation, then switch the preferred language back?

```
var preferred = $translate.preferredLanguage();
$translate.use('de')
$translate('HEADLINE').then(function(headline){
   $scope.translatedGerman = headline;
});
$translate.use(preferred);
```

Seems to be working in my simple demo at least: http://plnkr.co/edit/tPRbH7Oehy1nycBVopUw?p=preview